# GCP Billing API caching information?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to list all the regions where a given service is available, found out that the billing API could give me this information and decided to give it a try.

The problem is that when I list the Service Regions, it returns me also the results from the previous requests, I'm wondering if this may be based in a RPC and it's not clearing the cache or if there is some way to get a right result.

Code follows.

```
public class CloudbillingBuilder{

public static Cloudbilling createCloudbillingService()
      throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    // TODO: Verify Credentials using files/env vars
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
    if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
      credential =
          credential.createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
    }

     Cloudbilling cloudbillingService = new Cloudbilling.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
      .setApplicationName("Google Cloud Platform le")
      .build();

    return cloudbillingService;

  }

}


public class ServiceAvailabilityChecker{

// private String sku;
private String serviceName;
// private ListSkusResponse listSkus;
private java.util.List<Sku> listSkus;



public ServiceAvailabilityChecker(String skuCode)
    throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

    // this.sku = sku;

    Cloudbilling cloudbillingService = CloudbillingBuilder.createCloudbillingService();
    Cloudbilling.Services.Skus skurequest = cloudbillingService.services().skus();

    ListSkusResponse response = skurequest.list(skuCode).execute();

    listSkus = response.getSkus();
    
}

public List<String> getRegions(){
    List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(Sku sku : listSkus){
        // response.add(sku.getServiceRegions());
        response.addAll(sku.getServiceRegions());
    }
    return response;
}

public boolean isAvailable(String region){
    for(String str : getRegions()){
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    return false;
}
```

The isAvailable is printing the following:

```
    asia-east1
    asia-northeast1
    asia-northeast2
    europe-north1
    europe-west1
    europe-west4
    us-central1
    us-east1
    us-east4
    us-west1
    asia-east2
    asia-south1
    asia-southeast1
    australia-southeast1
    europe-west2
    europe-west3
    europe-west6
    southamerica-east1
    northamerica-northeast1
    us-west2
    europe-north1
    europe-west1
    europe-west2
    europe-west3
    europe-west4
    europe-west6
    global
    asia-east1
    asia-east2
    asia-northeast1
    asia-northeast2
    asia-northeast3
    asia-south1
    asia-southeast1
    asia-southeast2
    europe-north1
    europe-west1
    europe-west2
    europe-west3
    europe-west4
    europe-west6
    global
    southamerica-east1
    asia-east1
    asia-northeast1
    asia-northeast2
    europe-north1
    europe-west1
    europe-west4
    us-central1
    us-east1
    us-east4
    us-west1
    global
    asia-east2
    asia-south1
    asia-southeast1
    australia-southeast1
    europe-west2
    europe-west3
    europe-west6
    southamerica-east1
    northamerica-northeast1
    us-west2
    asia-east1
    asia-east2
    asia-northeast1
    asia-northeast2
    asia-northeast3
    asia-south1
    asia-southeast1
    asia-southeast2
    global
    asia-east1
    asia-east2
    asia-northeast1
    asia-northeast2
    asia-northeast3
    asia-south1
    asia-southeast1
    asia-southeast2
    europe-north1
    europe-west1
    europe-west2
    europe-west3
    europe-west4
    europe-west6
    northamerica-northeast1
    us-central1
    us-east1
    us-east4
    us-west1
    us-west2
    us-west3
    us-west4
    global
    northamerica-northeast1
    us-central1
    us-east1
    us-east4
    us-west1
    us-west2
    us-west3
    us-west4
    global
    global
    northamerica-northeast1
    us-central1
    us-east1
    us-east4
    us-west1
    us-west2
    us-west3
    us-west4
    australia-southeast1
```

Comment: Can you print the SKU in addition of the region list? Not sure that's an issue

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere You can, but, I've noticed that I was interpreting wrong the whole thing, when I print out the SKU from the parent, it has nested a lof of other SKUs. 

For Instance, if I print out the SKU of GKE, it also has regional, zonal, and Anthos GKE Services, which have different availability zones. So it wasn't cashing anything, it was properly replying but with all the nested siblings of a given service.

So it was indeed not an issue.